# Schema specified is not valid Membership.CreateUser

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I've been tasked with migrating from our old half-baked user store (using encrypted passwords) to the default MS membership/role providers. I've done this in other projects no problem.

In this case, I have created the necessary tables using code-first with the 'new' .NET universal providers. I am simply trying to insert new records into the Users table, and have run into a wall.

I have a simple edmx with the 6 tables created by the membership provider. I have set up my web.config to point to the necessary cxn string & membership/role providers (code below).

Web.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.Test.csdl|res://*/Entities.Test.ssdl|res://*/Entities.Test.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[OurServer];initial catalog=[OurDb];integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="Test" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="Test" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Here is my "update passwords" function:

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus status = new System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus();

//Get list of existing users, containing Username & encrypted PW
List<UserMigration.Models.Users> usersList = UserMigration.Models.Users.GetUsers();

foreach (var user in usersList)
{
    string password = "";
    //We have two encryption methods (bogus I know), so I attempt to decrypt with one, then another, using existing utility functions.
    if (!EncryptDecrypt.TryDecryptTripleDES(user.Password, out password))
    {
        EncryptDecrypt.TryDecrypt(user.Password, out password);
    }
    //if we got a password, lets party
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(user.Username, password,string.Empty,null,null,true,out status);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on the CreateUser call, and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I haven't modified the Entities in any way. This should be dirt simple. The error is:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The relationship 'TestModel.MembershipEntity_Application' was not loaded because the type 'TestModel.Membership' is not available.

The relationship 'TestModel.RoleEntity_Application' was not loaded because the type 'TestModel.Role' is not available.

The relationship 'TestModel.User_Application' was not loaded because the type 'TestModel.User' is not available.
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
The required property 'Roles' does not exist on the type 'System.Web.Providers.Entities.User'.
```

Comment: Don't you have to roll your own MembershipProvider to use EntityFramework?

Comment: not in mvc4 with universal providers.